# Rails minitest devise error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, testing, devise, minitest

I'm currently working on my first tests but I'm stuck with a problem I can't seem to fix by myself. I've searched for solutions for some hours now and found similar errors but I didn't find any solution working in my case. Maybe it's because of a version difference, I don't know.

The problem appears when I'm writing a unit test with minitest, maybe also integration tests. I'm using devise for managing users.

This is there error that appears in the terminal when I `rake test`:

```
1) Error:
test_deactivate_enrolment(EnrolmentTest):
NoMethodError: undefined method `env' for nil:NilClass
    /Users/myname/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/devise-3.0.3/lib/devise/test_helpers.rb:24:in `setup_controller_for_warden'
    /Users/myname/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:429:in `_run__840473936918917337__setup__1779200460764756091__callbacks'
    /Users/myname/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
    /Users/myname/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_setup_callbacks'
    /Users/myname/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
    /Users/myname/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/testing/setup_and_teardown.rb:35:in `run'
    /Users/myname/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/minitest/unit.rb:919:in `block in _run_suite'
    /Users/myname/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/minitest/unit.rb:912:in `map'
    /Users/myname/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/minitest/unit.rb:912:in `_run_suite'
    /Users/myname/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/test/unit.rb:657:in `block in _run_suites'
    /Users/myname/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/test/unit.rb:655:in `each'
    /Users/myname/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/test/unit.rb:655:in `_run_suites'
    /Users/myname/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/minitest/unit.rb:867:in `_run_anything'
    /Users/myname/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/minitest/unit.rb:1060:in `run_tests'
    /Users/myname/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/minitest/unit.rb:1047:in `block in _run'
    /Users/myname/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/minitest/unit.rb:1046:in `each'
    /Users/myname/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/minitest/unit.rb:1046:in `_run'
    /Users/myname/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/minitest/unit.rb:1035:in `run'
    /Users/myname/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/test/unit.rb:21:in `run'
    /Users/myname/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/test/unit.rb:774:in `run'
    /Users/myname/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/test/unit.rb:366:in `block (2 levels) in autorun'
    /Users/myname/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/test/unit.rb:27:in `run_once'
    /Users/myname/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/test/unit.rb:365:in `block in autorun'
```

This is what my `spec_helper.rb` looks like:

```
require 'listen'

Dir["#{File.dirname(__FILE__)}/support/**/*.rb"].each { |f| require f }

# See http://rubydoc.info/gems/rspec-core/RSpec/Core/Configuration
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.color_enabled = true
  config.order = :random
  config.filter_run :focus => true
  config.treat_symbols_as_metadata_keys_with_true_values = true
  config.run_all_when_everything_filtered = true
  config.filter_run_excluding :broken => true
  config.fail_fast = true
end

def test_latency
  0.1
end

# Crash loud in tests!
Thread.abort_on_exception = true
```

And this is my `test_helper.rb`

```
ENV["RAILS_ENV"] = "test"
require File.expand_path("../../config/environment", __FILE__)
require "rails/test_help"

# To add Capybara feature tests add `gem "minitest-rails-capybara"`
# to the test group in the Gemfile and uncomment the following:
#require "minitest/rails/capybara"

# Uncomment for awesome colorful output
#require "minitest/pride"
require 'minitest/autorun'

class ActiveSupport::TestCase
  # Setup all fixtures in test/fixtures/*.(yml|csv) for all tests in alphabetical order.
  fixtures :all
  include Devise::TestHelpers

  # Add more helper methods to be used by all tests here...
end
```

I've tried adding `include Devise::TestHelpers` on top of the files which fail but that didn't fix it. Deleting the line in 'test_helper.rb` had the same result. Maybe someone had this error as well?

**Update**

This is on of the test files, nothing too advanced...

require 'test_helper'

```
class EnrolmentTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
  test "deactivate enrolment" do
     assert true
  end
end
```

Comment: I updated the question with one of the test files that fail while testing. The other ones look exactly the same

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Only include the Devise helpers in your controller tests. Your `test_helper.rb` file should look like this:

```
ENV["RAILS_ENV"] = "test"
require File.expand_path("../../config/environment", __FILE__)
require "rails/test_help"

# To add Capybara feature tests add `gem "minitest-rails-capybara"`
# to the test group in the Gemfile and uncomment the following:
#require "minitest/rails/capybara"

# Uncomment for awesome colorful output
#require "minitest/pride"
require 'minitest/autorun'

class ActiveSupport::TestCase
  # Setup all fixtures in test/fixtures/*.(yml|csv) for all tests in alphabetical order.
  fixtures :all

  # Add more helper methods to be used by all tests here...
end

class ActionController::TestCase
  include Devise::TestHelpers
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Alternative, you can use Warden to test instead of Device test helpers, [here there is an example of use](https://github.com/hassox/warden/wiki/Testing). Devise is based on Warden.

Answer (score 1):

Remove `include Devise::TestHelpers` from your test_helper.rb. Include it only in the test that needs it.